# Class hierarchy of Shopping Cart Price Rules

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Class `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` has an object of `salesrule/rule_collection`, and that object calls a function `validate` of class    `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Found`, what I didn't understand is how the object of `salesrule/rule_collection` is related to Found class, and if we add any other function to this class and try to access it will throw an Exception *Undefined Function*, I just want to understand whats going on behind the scenes

`Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Found` extends the class `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Combine` but when from `process` function of the 
`Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` called it calls the `validate` function of the `Found` class `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` object call to `process`

```
try {
   $validator = Mage::getModel('module/validator')
                    ->init($customer->getWebsiteId(), $customerGroupId);
} catch (Exception $e) {
   Mage::log('Exception: ' . $e . ' in ' . __CLASS__ . ' on ' . __LINE__);
}
$v  = $validator->process($quote);
```

And the `process` function of `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` which calls the `validate` function of `Found` class

```
public function process($_quote) 
{
         $quote           = $_quote;
         $customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
         foreach ($this->_rules as $rule) {

            if ($rule->getIsValid() === false) {
              continue;
            }
            if ($rule->getIsValid() !== true) { 
                $rule->afterLoad();
                if (!$rule->validate($quote)) { // quote does not meet rule's conditions , //Call Found.php
                $rule->setIsValid(false);
                continue;
                }
                $rule->setIsValid(true); // passed all validations, remember to be valid
            }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

And the `validate` function of `Found` class

```
   public function validate(Varien_Object $object) 
   {
//Called form Validator.php
    $all       = $this->getAggregator() === 'all';
    $true      = (bool)$this->getValue();
    $found     = false;

    $Count =  count($object->getAllItems()); 
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($object->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $found = $all ? true : false;
        foreach ($this->getConditions() as $cond) {

            $validated = $cond->validate($item); // Call to Product.php's function 'validate'

            if($validated) {
                $this->_ProductId[] = $item->getProductId();
            }

            if($i == $Count) {
                if ($all && !$validated) {
                $found = false;
                break;
                } elseif (!$all && $validated) {
                $found = true;
                break 2;
                }
            }

                }
            if($i == $Count) {
            if ($found && $true) {
                break;
            }
            }
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Now what I didn't understand is if I write any other function in `Found` class let it be `public function Foo()` and try to call it from `process` function of class `Validator` like

```
    $rule->Foo();
```

it will throw an Exception *Undefined Function*
I just want to know the reason why I can't write any function in `Found` class and call like `process`
Thanks

Comment: I found [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/ReflectionClass) coming in handy while working with Magento. Especially in combination with [ReflectionClass::getMethod()](http://md1.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethod.php) and ReflectionMethod::getFilename() to find the files I needed.
I do not completly understand what you are trying to accomplish, but it may help you anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Magento's core developers sometimes like to use additional abstraction that makes things a bit more difficult to see. Why? maybe they intended to develop this section further, maybe they thought it makes it even easier to override, one thing is certain they didn't think of the cost associated with complexity.

The whole salesrule module is broken down to many many subclasses of which each individual class holds a unique piece of logic. The core logic actually lies within that main file you were looking at: `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` inside the **process()** method.

The line you are referring to is 294 in the code, which is inside a loop of all the rules applied to the specific quote item (a quote item is essentially a product that was added to the shopping cart and converted to hold additional meta data).

```
    if (!$rule->getActions()->validate($item)) {
        continue;
    }
```

So here they are using same strategy as within the product and product types. You got a rule as a general model and a bunch of sibling classes that each hold unique logic. The Found/Combine/Subselect child classes of a rule (which help facilitate the logic of AND/OR and combo rules with priorities). Here is the kicker: A **Rule** in Magento was abstracted to its own unique module. Take a look at Mage_Rule module - that is probably where you will find all the missing pieces.

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks Ron, your answer really helped me, I up voted it :)
But not an exact solution to my question, so I will wait for solved answer or will post it myself if I found

Comment: Hi Ahmed, please share some code so we get a better idea on what you are referring to. Let's try and narrow it down to what you got going.